# How to add .Net control in MSAccess 2003 form?

Tags: .net, controls, ms-office

I have a requirement to add like a cardfile control to a MSAccess 2003 form (tab page of a tab control).

What would be the best method to do this writing it in .NET???

Any suggestions to get me started??

Malcolm

Answer (score 1):

You have to compile it as an ActiveX control since Access 2003 is a COM client and can't run managed code directly.

It's a little bit involved, but here is a decent tutorial on how to do that:
[Writing an ActiveX Control in .NET](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/dsandor/activexinnet11102005040748am/activexinnet.aspx)

However, if the end goal is to just add a "cardfile control" assuming you are talking about a tab control to an Access form, you are better off not using .NET at all. Just use the built-in Access tab control instead.